# How do to create a Spring MVC project in STS 4?

Tags: java, spring, spring-tool-suite

I am using `Spring Tool Suite 4` but its hasn't option to create Spring MVC project. I would like to create a `Spring MVC` project with `Thymeleaf`.

How do I to create Spring MVC with Spring Tools 4 ?

Comment: Did you got the solution? If yes can you please share?